# Software or Softwares

Tags: technical-writing, word-choice, grammar

It seems to me that *softwares* is incorrect. I am of the opinion that software is partitive. I try to use *some software* or *piece of software*.

Do you think it is incorrect to say *softwares*?

Comment: Like all uncountable nouns, *software* doesn't normally take a plural form, so yes it is incorrect (except in certain rare contexts).

Comment: To those proposing to migrate this question to [ELU.se], please note that it would quickly be closed on that site for "lack of research, or consider [ELL.se]". In such cases, migration simply creates more work for other SE users undertaking community moderation tasks.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica It would certainly be nice if we had an ELL migration option, but last I looked that request was declined as insufficiently common to be worth the effort.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica well it certainly doesn't belong here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Software engineer i can say "Softwares" is incorrect.

Comment: Agreed. I've heard "softwares," but never from someone who spoke English as their first language.